# M2Eclipse throwing java.langg.NoClassDefFoundError when updating maving project

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, ibm-rad

I have a fresh install of IBM's Rational Application Developer v9.1.  It is based on Eclipse 4.2.1.  It uses M2E 1.4.0.

However, when I import an existing Maven project, or attempt to do a Maven->Update Configuration, it throws the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.PlexusIoResourceCollection
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:94)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:92)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:92)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:92)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepare(J9VMInternals.java:516)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:560)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:629)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:831)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:758)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:255)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:204)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:954)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:987)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:950)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1000)
    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:965)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1018)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:961)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:83)
    at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.locators.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:49)
    at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.binders.PlexusRequirements$RequirementProvider.get(PlexusRequirements.java:217)
    at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.binders.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty(ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:45)
    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.inject.BeanInjector.injectMembers(BeanInjector.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:128)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:117)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:259)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:965)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1018)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:961)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1000)
    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
    at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.lifecycles.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:138)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:965)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1011)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:961)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:83)
    at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.locators.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:253)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:245)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.getConfiguredMojo(MavenImpl.java:342)
    at org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.reflectManifestGeneration(AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java:406)
    at org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.generateManifest(AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java:364)
    at org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.mavenProjectChanged(AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java:183)
    at org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator$1.build(AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.MavenProjectManager.execute(MavenProjectManager.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1305)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.PlexusIoResourceCollection
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
    ... 98 more
```

I went hunting around, and found that the class in question exists in the org.codehaus.plexus.plexus-io package.  I downloaded it from Maven Central (I guessed at the version and d/l'ed 2.0.6) and added the jar to my plugins/ folder, but it has not made any difference.

Just to be on the safe side, I even added it to my jre/lib folder but I still get the same error message.

How do I resolve this?  The RAD installation will not allow me to uninstall M2E and install a newer version, so I'm kind of with 1.4.0.

Is there anything I can try?

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>test</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Did you try Project -> Clean?

Comment: @benji - no but given it is a brand new project that I am importing (nothing other than a POM and some src .java files) there is nothing to clean.  Plus, I saw this as an Eclipse error rather than a project specific error.  My Maven project is the simplest pom.xml (has 3 deps on Velocity, CommonsPool and JodaTime) and a single Main class.

Comment: I agree. I found eclipse to behave weird many times. I re-read your question and realized that the error happens when you import the maven project into eclipse.. so I guess clean is not related.. can you paste your pom?

Comment: @benji - I added the pom.xml defn.  Just to be thorough, I did try to clean the project, but get the same error: "Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'test2'."  And the same stack trace in the Error Log.  I did manage to remove M2E 1.4.0 and upgrade to 1.4.1, but no added benefit.  Same error messages.

Comment: can you build it outside of eclipse?

Comment: @benji Fair question.  Hadn't actually tried before your post, but yes - I just tried an can run `mvn package` successfully from cmd prompt

Comment: Seems like maybe it can't be accessed by m2e.. can you try to add the missing jar to MANIFEST.MF under <eclipse folder>\plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime<version>\META-INF, to the end of the Bundle-ClassPath property?

Comment: @benji - I'm not entirely sure how to specify the path.  All the entries in Bundle-ClassPath are listed as relative paths "jars/xxx.jar", etc.  If I look for the files, they all point to `configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/3711/1/.cp/jars`.  Should I drop my missing jar in that same path?  Otherwise, what kind of path to I specify for the class path?

Comment: @benji - I tried dropping it in the jars/ folder and adding the jar to to the Bundle-ClassPath at the end, but to no avail.  Still same error.

Comment: @benji - After a lot of testing, I finally found a configuration that works.  Removing all m2e connectors, and installing just "Maven Integration for Eclipse" (none of the optional ones) without the m2e-wtp plugin worked.

It seems as though the m2e-wtp plugin is triggering this error msg.  If I install the m2e-wtp plugin, the error reappears.  If I delete it, the error goes away.